# How to handle Spring data exceptions in the repository layer

Tags: spring, exception

I am writing a REST application using Spring. It is divided into 3 layers, controller, service and repository.

The repository layer are using Spring data and MongoDb. The exceptions from MongoDb are translated to Spring Data exceptions.

Using the @ExceptionHandler annotation I tried to catch those exceptions in the repository layer. This did not work. The only way to catch the exception with @ExceptionHandler is to put the code in the controller layer.

Is there a way for me to catch and handle the exceptions in the repository layer,, without using try/catch blocks.

Comment: It's the repository layer (i.e. the Spring proxies around your repositories) that throw these exceptions, so I don't see how you could catch the in the repository layer. What's the point, anyway?

Comment: Handling the exception as close as possible to the origin.

Comment: In this case, it would mean catching the exception before it has even been thrown. You could catch them in the service layer, but what would be the point? Could you do anything other than what is done by default (rollbacking the transaction and propagate the exception).

Comment: How do I catch them in the service layer without using a try/catch block?

Comment: I don't know, because I still don't understand why you want to catch the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be done with Spring AOP and by creating an @Around advice for all your DAO methods as shown below.

But I would still like to understand what you plan to do in your catch block. Are you planning to have different logic to handle different types of data access exceptions? If you don't have any specific logic, it makes sense to just let the exception propagate to the controller layer.

**First Option**

Here is a sample -

```
    @Aspect
public class DaoExceptionHandlerAdvice {
    @Around("execution( * com.xyz.daos.*.*(..))")
    public Object invokeService(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature)pjp.getSignature();
        Object returnValue = null;
        try {
            returnValue = pjp.proceed();
        } 
        catch(Exception e){
            // handle the exception 
        }
        finally{
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Add following snippet in your application context file

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />    
<bean id="daoExceptionHandler" class="com.xyz.advice.DaoExceptionHandlerAdvice"  ></bean>
```

Check out the following link for details - 
[Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html)

**Second Option**

I've not tried this, but it would probably be easier for you to use an exception translator. You could probably extend HibernateExceptionTranslator and have your own logic in there.

Follow this link for details - 
[Exception Translation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-exception-translation)

Comment: Thanks. I've been thinking in that direction (aop) and your answer tells me there are no other solution.

To the question,, "what are you going to do with this" ??

To be honest,, I assumed there would be some exception (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/dao.html)  that the repository layer could recover from. When you so strongly insist on just letting the exceptions propagate to the controller layer I am getting second toughs. At the moment I just are trying to set up a "template" for my application.

Comment: You are right, unless you have a specific type of exception or a specific scenario where you want to recover from an exception, catching it at the repository layer is not necessary. You could probably handle those few scenarios by adding 'catch' blocks in your service layer. If you still want to add a generic exception handler, be sure to check out the 'exception translator' option that I've mentioned in my answer.